# How to setup fabric-sample test-network without TLS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to run test-network in fabric sample without TLS. for that what I need to change in fabric-sample?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should do to disable TLS of a fabric network

1. Disable TLS for orderers and peers

   By default mode of test-network, set [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml#L31) to `false` to disable  TLS of the orderer. Same as  [peer0.org1](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml#L72) and [peer0.org2](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml#L109)
2. Not using TLS for every script call in the folder `fabric-samples/test-network/scripts`. The option for TLS is `--tls`. You can remove this option (`--tls`), or set it to false by adding `false` after the option

   For example, the [update anchor peer function call](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/scripts/setAnchorPeer.sh#L44)

   ```
   updateAnchorPeer() {
       peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}anchors.tx --tls false --cafile "$ORDERER_CA" >&log.txt
       res=$?
       cat log.txt
       verifyResult $res "Anchor peer update failed"
       successln "Anchor peer set for org '$CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID' on channel '$CHANNEL_NAME'"
   }
   ```

Do this  to every script, which use `--tls` option